# Bus error when trying to write in FILE

Tags: c++, bus-error

I am trying to generate a matrix of all ones in C++, using an 2D array, however i have a BUS ERROR when trying to write more than 735 characters, I think I have problems with memory allocation, can you help me please?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

#define symbols 800

int main ()

{

    fstream file("/Users/Caste/Documents/MAESTRIA/PROGRAMMING TEST/CAPACITY/test1.txt",ios::out);

    int *ptr;
    ptr =(int*)calloc(symbols, sizeof(symbols));
    int i,j,array[1][symbols];
    for (i=0; i<1; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<symbols; j++) 
            array[1][symbols]=1;
    }
    cout << "Array indicates:\n";
    for (i=0; i<1; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<symbols; j++) 

            file<<array[1][symbols];
            file.close();

        cout << "\n";
        }
```

Comment: This is an unholy mix of C and C++. Good C++ looks different.

Answer (score 3):

There are probably other errors, but for starters, you're
using `array[1]` (the second element), when `array` only have
one element (of `int[symbols]` type).  Undefined behavior, and
since you're writing, you're certainly corrupting other objects
on the stack.

The `calloc` looks more than a little strange as well; it's the
first time I've seen an element size specified with `sizeof`
a constant.  In this case, the constant has type `int`, and
you're allocating to an `int*`, so you might have lucked out.
But `std::vector<int>` would seem more appropriate.

And of course, you're closing the file after the first write,
which means that all later writes will be no-ops.

Answer (score 1):

Within your loops you are accessing the array via the constants used to declare it:

```
array[1][symbols]
```

You should be using your loop variables:

```
array[i][j]
```

Comment: But also note that since it's defined as `[1]`, that the *only* subscript you can use is `0`, *not* `1`.

Comment: Agreed. Luckily the loop over `i` is okay for that (`for (i=0; i<1; i++)
`).

Comment: Right -- but I think you're exactly correct to attribute it to luck.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys for your help,it was really helpful, here I post the final code which I reduce it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

#define symbols 1000000
//#define SNR 7

int main () 
{
    fstream file("/Users/Caste/Documents/MAESTRIA/PROGRAMMING TEST/CAPACITY/test1.txt",ios::out);
    int channel[1][symbols];
    memset((void*)channel, '\0', symbols);
    for (int i=0; i<1; i++) 
        for (int j=0; j<symbols; j++) {
            channel[i][j]=1;
        }
    for (int i=0; i<1; i++) {
        cout << endl;
        for (int j=0; j<symbols; j++) 
            //cout << channel[i][j];
            file<<channel[i][j];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ptr =(int*)calloc(symbols, sizeof(symbols));`
should be
`ptr =(int*)calloc(symbols, sizeof(int));`

I'm not sure that is causing your problem directly though.

Answer (score 0):

There are many logical errors in your program, but I believe the problem that is causing the crash is that you are closing the file in your nested loop and then trying to write to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to write a bunch of '1's to a file, why not something like:

```
std::ofstream file("whatever path");

std::fill_n(std::ostream_iterator<int>(file), how_many, 1);
```

Edit: To put the data in a vector first, then copy to the file, you could do something like this:

```
std::vector<int> data;

std::fill_n(std::back_inserter(data), how_many, 1);
```

and to copy that to the file, you'd do something like:

```
std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(file));
```

Comment: Thanks, this work, however I would like to generate 1000000 ones, and put it inside a vector, because later on I will use this vector in a different processing, thanks for your help in advanced.